# copy a div content to another div

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I want to copy a div content to another div without assigning them id's or class name i.e., onclick of a div the content will be copied to a variable then click on other div the variable content should be copied to that div.

I want to achieve this by using jquery.

EDIT:
I have tried this code:

```
<div>content</div>
<div>paste the above content here</div>​
```

---

```
div{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid black;
   cursor:pointer;
}​
```

but i dont know what to implement in the part of jquery.

please assist

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant.

Comment: Without assigning id or class names? How are you gonna select the element you want?

Comment: $("tr:odd td:odd") something like that

Comment: you can use this: `$(new_div).html(old_div.innerHTML);`

Comment: It'd be easier to give you the exact answer, if you post your HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var buffer = '';

//onclick of a div
$('div').click(function(){
    if(buffer == ''){
        // the content will be copied to a variable
        buffer = $(this).text();
    } else {
        // click on other div the variable content should be copied to that div
        $(this).text(buffer);
    }
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6QrL/1/)

**UPD**: you might want to replace `text()` to `html()` to copy the whole content of your `div`, not just text.

Comment: Hey its not working. it was working good in your jsfiddle example but when i implemented it, nothing happened. Maybe im doing something wrong.

Comment: maybe, open a new question and post some code, there's no way to tell what's wrong without the code.

Comment: put your code inside DOM ready event, so it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UGt7U/1/ Right now you are trying to use jQuery before it was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You must give id or class name to any element (in your case div) to select that particular element using jQuery. Otherwise how jQuery is going to identify which element(in your case div) you want to insert the data.
And if their are only two divs in your page you can access them using the order of divs inside the page even if they dont have class name or id.

Comment: if we assign id's to each element then there is no difference in jquery and javascript. i think so.

Comment: jQuery is just a library built with JavaScript to help JavaScript programmers do their tasks easily. So in both this their should be a selector(id,name,class) for an element to exactly identify a particular element or elements in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Though not so clear from your post, but from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234501/copy-a-div-content-to-another-div/12234555#comment16395899_12234501) guess something like this:

```
var _content;

$('tr:odd td:odd').on('click', function() {
   _content = $(this).html();
});

$('tr:even td:even').on('click', function() {
   $(this).html( _content );
});
```